# Javascript generated select not posting in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I have searched far and wide and have not seen an answer for this. Forgive me if one exists.

I have a PHP page, in which user can generate new html select fields by pressing a button. I use Javascript to generate the new select fields. The user can then select one option from the generated select field. I need the value the user chose in PHP code below the form, to submit the form values to database.

My problem is that PHP doesn't seem to recognize the new generated select fields, which is why it won't post. 
`var_dump($_POST)` doesn't show the new select field. I have also tried to name the new select as `name="choice1[]"`, but that also has not posted. Choice1 is always undefined.

All of my code is on the same PHP page, apart from sql query to populate the select options.

This is what Javascript generates inside a form:

```
<select class="form-control" id="choose1" name="choice1">
    <option value="1:x">Text</option>
    <option value="2:y">Text</option>
    <option value="3:z">Text</option>
</select>
```

This is where I try to get the value, after submit button is pressed:

```
if (isset($_POST['choice1'])){
    $choice1 = $_POST['choice1'];
    $parts1 = $choice1;
    $arr1 = explode(':', $parts1);
    $tNum = $arr1[0];
    $tName = $arr1[1];
}
```

The Javascript works fine, the values are shown on the page fine. The only part not working is the post method (well, only for this specific select field. Other's work fine, as those are hard coded to html). Submit button works fine, everything else gets submitted.

My question is if there is a way for me to get the post values in PHP without reloading the page?
Or if reload is needed, how to do this without closing the form modal?
Or even more of a general question would be.. How do I do this?

**EDIT:**

Here is my form code. I deleted bunch of other stuff from it just to show the parts I have the problem with. If the divs are weird, it's because of that.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Change</h4>
    </div>
    <div class='modal-body'>
        <div class='row'>
        <label class="col-sm-3"> Product: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-8" id="selectProd"> 
            <!-- **This is where new select is generated** -->

            <select class='form-control' id='valinta' name='choice'>

            <?php
            $sql0= "SELECT tuotenro, tuotenimi FROM vaateHenkilot WHERE asnro = '". $_GET['b']."' AND henknro = '". $_GET['a']."' GROUP BY tuotenro, tuotenimi";
            $req =  sqlsrv_query($con, $sql0) or die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true));

            $t = '';

            while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($req)) {
                $t = array(
                    array (
                        'nro' => $row['tuotenro'],
                        'nimi' => $row['tuotenimi'],
                    )
                 );
                 $tuotteetIN = array_column($t, 'nimi', 'nro');

                 foreach($tuotteetIN as $key => $value) {
                 ?>
                 <option value="<?php echo $key ?>:<?php echo $value ?>"><?php echo $value ?></option>
                 <?php
                 }
             }
             ?>
            </select>
            <br>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-1">
               <button type='button' class='btn' onclick='addSelectBox()'>+</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="saveButton">Save</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</form>
<?php

if (isset($_POST['saveButton'])) {
    $choice = $_POST["choice"];
    $parts = $choice;
    $arr = explode(':', $parts);
    $tNum = $arr[0];
    $tName = $arr[1];

    if (isset($_POST['choice1'])){
        $choice1 = $_POST['choice1'];
        $parts1 = $choice1;
        $arr1 = explode(':', $parts1);
        $tNum = $arr[0] . ', ' . $arr1[0];
        $tName = $arr[1] . ', ' . $arr1[1];
    }

     *Here is the sql query*
}
?>
```

I have another select there, which has the same values. That one works well.
I'll add the Javascript here that creates the new select, as well.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var j = 0;
    function addSelectBox (){
        if (j < 3){
            var parentDiv = document.getElementById ("selectProd");
            var selectElement = document.createElement ("select");

            j++;
            selectElement.setAttribute("class", "form-control");
            selectElement.setAttribute("id", "choose" + j);
            selectElement.setAttribute("name", "choice" + j);

            var tuotteet = '';
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'productHelp.php?asi=<?php echo $asnro; ?>&hen=<?php echo $henro; ?>',
                data: tuotteet,
                datatype: 'json',
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    var tnimi = data.split(";");
                    for (var i=0;i < tnimi.length -1;i++){
                        var tnro = tnimi[i].split(",");

                        var option = new Option (tnro[1], tnro[0]+":"+tnro[1]);
                        selectElement.options[selectElement.options.length] = option;
                    }
                }
            });

            parentDiv.appendChild (selectElement);
            parentDiv.appendChild(linebreak);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: make sure this select is inside the same form that gets submitted. If it is, then please share the form code with us.

Comment: If you hard-code the `<select>`, does it get submitted?

Comment: `"I understand that PHP runs server side and probably won't get the changes to the site without a reload."` That's not how it works. All form elements inside the form are submitted to the server, no matter if it was in the markup on page load or added later. So probably Pavel Lint is right about assuming that the select is not being added to the correct form.

Comment: Here's a PHP file that works fine: https://pastebin.com/AZWMnn0V (that PHP runs server-side means PHP only becomes involved again after the browser makes a second request to the server, either by the user submitting the form or by using AJAX)

Comment: I've added the form code. @PavelLint

Comment: Also thank you @ConstantinGroß for explaining that! Helps me to understand this way better.

Comment: @VanillaMilla your JS code seems to be valid. It must work. Check what your browser actually sends to the server at Network tab of the Dev Console. There must be all of select-fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was as "stupid" and simple as I figured it had to be. 
Taking the modals with the functionality out from the table structure made it work fine.

Good to learn something new about formatting everyday!